# Format an object by fields

Tags: javascript, object

```
const data = {
   language: 'en',
   type: 'trx',
   country: 'Croatia',
   Method: 'trx_pay',
   Email: 'email',
   Phone: '123',
   City: 'Zagreb'
}
```

I need format the above object into such format:

```
const data = {
   language: 'en',
   type: 'trx',
   country: 'Croatia',
   userData: {
     Method: 'trx_pay',
     Email: 'email',
     Phone: '123',
     City: 'Zagreb'
   }
}
```

All the fields in PascalCase should be put into a nested object. Also, I know exactly the fields in camelCase (language, type and country).

Here's what I've tried so far using Lodash:

```
const staticKeys = ['language', 'type', 'country']; // These keys can't changes

const staticData = pick(data, staticKeys);
const userData = omit(data, staticKeys);

const res = { ...staticData, userData };
```

Is there a more elegant way to do it without Lodash?

Comment: I'd say having 3 lines of actual code is pretty elegant already.

Comment: Is there something particular that you don't like about your current solution? (ie: you don't want to use lodash, you want it to be fewer lines, etc...?)

Comment: @NickParsons Thanks for the suggestion! Yes, I'd like to see a solution without Lodash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use lodash, you can make use of [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Since you know the static keys, you can destructure them (rather than put them into an array), and use the [rest syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring) (`...`) to obtain all the other remaining properties:

```js
const data = { language: 'en', type: 'trx', country: 'Croatia', Method: 'trx_pay', Email: 'email', Phone: '123', City: 'Zagreb' };

const {language, type, country, ...userData} = data;
const res = {language, type, country, userData};
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a vanilla js loop of the Object.entries()

```js
const staticKeys = ['language', 'type', 'country'];

const data = {
   language: 'en',
   type: 'trx',
   country: 'Croatia',
   Method: 'trx_pay',
   Email: 'email',
   Phone: '123',
   City: 'Zagreb'
}

const res = {userData:{}}

Object.entries(data).forEach(([k,v])=> (staticKeys.includes(k) ? res : res.userData)[k] = v)

console.log(res)
```